# additional conditions on join in django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to add an additional condition to join statement created by django ORM?

What I need in SQL is

```
'SELECT "post"."id", COUNT("watchlist"."id") FROM "post" 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "watchlist" 
    ON ("post"."id" = "watchlist"."post_id" AND "watchlist"."user_id" = 1) 
 WHERE "post"."id" = 123  GROUP BY …
```

In django most of this is

```
Post.objects.annotate(Count('watchinglist')).get(pk=123)
```

But how can I add `AND "watchlist"."user_id" = …` into JOIN condition with django ORM?

Adding it to filter fails to get Post objects with no associated objects in watchlist.

Comment: Great question, not sure how this would be considered a duplicate of the tagged question. This question refers to adding additional filters to the relation, not simply performing one to begin with.

Comment: Right, this is distinct from the other question this has been marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 24):

In Django v2.0 use [FilteredRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects)

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    t=FilteredRelation(
        'watchlist', condition=Q(watchlist__user_id=1)
).filter(t__field__in=...)
```

Comment: This is the best direct answer to the question for newer versions of Django. But unfortunately FilteredRelation doesn't work across multiple relationships so is a bit half-baked at the moment.

Comment: I agree with @getup8, FilteredRelation is a half-baked feature, you cannot get the value of `t` with attribute access, it only works with `values`, `values_list`.

Comment: Note that there is a bug in < 3.0 versions if the relation query result is null.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29810 the only fix I found is to use a newer django.

Comment: I've tried this in Django 3.2 and works fine for my purpose (1 to many, not some complex query, I want to use `FilteredRelation` to join by adding an `AND` condition and then adding a filter on the `WHERE` clause). Seems to work fine, best answer so far I think (not sure about the cavecats mentioned by other people thought, maybe that won't work in all cases)

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: in certain conditions - yes.

When construction LEFT JOINs with GenericForeignKey, Django calls
[GenericRelation.get_extra_restriction](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2ced2f785d5aca0354abf5841d5449b7a49509dc/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py#L437) which adds extra condition to ON clause with "content_type_id" restriction.

For "ForeignKey" this method is also called by returns None.

You may use this place to put extra restrictions into ON clause, if you manage to organize your code to get proper restriction params at certain time.

```
class UserForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):

    def get_extra_restriction(self, where_class, alias, related_alias):
        field = self.model._meta.get_field('user')
        cond = where_class()
        # Here is a hack to get custom condition parameters
        value = SomeContextManager.get_needed_value()

        lookup = field.get_lookup('exact')(field.get_col(related_alias), value)
        cond.add(lookup, 'AND')
        return cond

class WatchList(models.Model):

    user = UserForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Post.objects.annotate(Count('watchinglist')).filter(pk=123).extra(where=['"watchlist"."user_id" = 1'])
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Looks like it acually does the same thing as filter(). E.g. adding one parameter to WHERE, not to ON, and, therefore, providing empty result if there's no watchinglist object.

Comment: But, actually, good idea. I missed the 'extra' parameter of Count. Looks like that one works.

Comment: ...or maybe not. 'extra' there seems to have somewhat different purpose.

Comment: The EXTRA doesn't add anything to the ON statement, but it add to WHERE and I used it to modify JOIN results by simply adding name of the joined table (T4, T5) in condition. It's not beautiful at all, but I think it's better than to use a custon SQL.