# Django join tables with two or more FK conditions

Tags: django, orm

I want to join models B and C with two conditions, data_a and human in model_B, and data_a and autor in model_C, but how do I do it with Django ORM

```
class user(models.Model):
    data_1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    data_2 = models.SmallIntegerField()
    data_3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class model_A(models.Model):
    data_1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    data_2 = models.SmallIntegerField()
    data_3 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)



class model_B(models.Model):
    data_a = models.ForeignKey(model_A)
    human = models.ForeignKey(user)
    data_2 = models.IntegerField()

class model_C(models.Model):
    data_a = models.ForeignKey(model_A)
    author = models.ForeignKey(user)
    data_1 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    data_2 = models.IntegerField()
```

[additional conditions on join in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328577/additional-conditions-on-join-in-django)

I've seen this place, but I don't know if it's applicable to my situation

Comment: """ SELECT mB.data_a,,, FROM model_B mB LEFT JOIN model_C mC ON mB.human_id = mC.author_id AND mB.data_a_id = mC.data_a_id """

I want to get the motion of this sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from django.db.models import F

result = model_B.objects.filter(
human__model_c__author=F('human'), 
data_a__model_c__data_a=F('data_a')
).values('data_a')
```

In this code, we're using the double underscore notation to traverse the relationships between the models and perform the join. The human__model_c__author and data_a__model_c__data_a represent the conditions you mentioned in your SQL query, where we check for equality between human_id and author_id, and between data_a_id and data_a_id. Finally, we use the values method to select the 'data_a' field from model_B.

This code will generate a query that's equivalent to your SQL query.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was confused
""" SELECT mB.data_a,,, FROM model_B mB LEFT JOIN model_C mC ON mB.human_id = mC.author_id AND mB.data_a_id = mC.data_a_id """

I want to get the motion of this sql query.